# What is extraReducers map object notion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

When read redux toolkit offical documet, I saw this in `createSlice` section:

```
const incrementBy = createAction('incrementBy')

createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [incrementBy]: (state, action) => {. ///what is this
      return state + action.payload
    },
    'some/other/action': (state, action) => {},
  },
})
```

I don't understand why we have `array` here. Why do we use `string` here and **why we use this in an array**  ( `[incrementBy`] )?

Please help, thank you a lots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an array, instead this is computed properties. This will add `key` to an object at run-time

```js
let prop = "name";
const obj = {
  [prop]: "Stackoverflow",
};
console.log(obj);
```

`extraReduce` is an object and in the code `incrementBy` will give property name, also you are assigning a function to that property name.

```js
let prop = "getSum";
const obj = {
  [prop]: (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);
  },
};
console.log(obj[prop]([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(obj.getSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: I got it, thank you so much, but i have another question, why we don't use directly `name:"Stackoverflow"` ?

Comment: It could be possible that the name of the property is not known before run-time. It may change also. It won't be static every time. Let say today you gave the name of the property as `getSum`, someone or your future self want to change the name to `addNumbers`. So you made it `dynamic` using computed properties.

Comment: There may be a change that the property name comes from somewhere else's code. It could be a library. So better to make it dynamic.